# Spark : How to append to cached rdd?

Tags: caching, apache-spark, spark-streaming

- Distinct values are cached with every streamed batch of data.
- How do i build the cache by adding the next distinct values in the next batch to the already cached RDD?

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly append your data with Rdd because its immutable. Using union to create new Rdd and then cache it.